# How to use Scrapy to scrape data from a website which has an option to Load More posts?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use scrapy to get title and date from all posts of the following website:
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/recos
I am new to scrapy and not able to understand how to load more posts and scrape them.

This is the code i wrote following a tutorial, but it only scraps the first few posts.

```py
import scrapy

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="posts"

    start_urls=[
        'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/recos'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        for post in response.css('div.eachStory'):
            yield{
                'title': post.css('a::text').get(),
                'date' : post.css('time::text').get()
            }
            next_page=response.css('div.autoload_continue').get()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I am printing it out in csv format using `scrapy crawl posts -o posts.csv`.
I am not sure if its even possible to do all the posts. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, `div.autoload_continue` does not contain any link. It is like a button that, if you click it, it requests with JavaScript. You can check the endpoint of the request by viewing in `Devtools > Networks`.

Here is what I see: the website requests this for first load
`https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/lazyloadlistnew.cms?msid=3053611&curpg=1&img=1`.
Then if I scroll down it requests 
`https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/lazyloadlistnew.cms?msid=3053611&curpg=2&img=1`
When I click *load more* it requests
`https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/lazyloadlistnew.cms?msid=3053611&curpg=3&img=0`

Look at the parameter `curpg`, which is increasing; it indicates the page.
You may just iterate numbers to change the `curpg` params.
 `img` param is a toggle to display the image.
 As for `msid` param, it's the id for article list. You can find that value from meta in head `<meta content="https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/recos/articlelist/3053611.cms" property="og:url">`